# Xubuntu 18.04.2 : Synaptic lists the network manager under Installed (local or obsolete)

Tags: synaptic

Xubuntu 18.04.2

In Synaptic > Status > Installed (local or obsolete) I have:

```
-- libnm-glib-vpn1
-- libnm-glib4
-- libnm-util2
-- libnm0
-- network-manager
```

all with {Installed,Latest} Version 1.10.14-0ubuntu2, as well as:

```
-- virtualbox-6.0
```

Indeed I installed virtualbox from the vendor, but I never did something "special" for the network-manager and its dependencies -- so they should not be listed here but under under Synaptic > Status > Installed.

When a new version for the network-manager will become available will the upgrade be effected via the Software Updater or will I have to do things manually?

Also how can I make them be listed under Synaptic > Status > Installed again?

Kind regards, Dick
:D

Comment: I use synaptic since Ubuntu 06 and never destroyed my OS ...

Comment: I never saw VirtualBox as coming from the vender (Oracle) being updated automatically ...

Comment: My question though was for network-manager and friends.